# Finding the common element between two result sets in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have created the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   idx SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   refs_person TEXT[],
   id_gps TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE table2 (
   idx SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   id_person TEXT,
   city TEXT,
   location INTEGER
);
```

I populated them with this information.

Table 1

```
idx  || refs_person                           ||  id_gps
 1   || {id_per_234, id_per_456}              ||  gps_20 
 2   || {id_per_568}                          ||  gps_23
 3   || {id_per_345, id_per_334, id_per_340}  ||  gps_45
```

Table 2

```
idx  || id_person    || city  || location
 1   || id_per_234   || Paris ||   20
 2   || id_per_999   || York  ||   20
 3   || id_per_213   || Paris ||   20
 4   || id_per_334   || Paris ||   32
```

If I try to find out *id_person* in *Paris* with location *20*.

```
select id_person from table2 where city = 'Paris' and location = '20';
    id_per_234
    id_per_213
```

Then, if I try to find out *refs_person* with *id_gps* *20* for table 1

```
 select refs_person from table1 where id_gps = '20';
       {id_per_234, id_per_456}
```

I'm having an issue relating to finding the common element between this two results.

For the this example, I want to get *id_per_234*.
I have tried using **intersect** statement without any success.

Any ideas?

Comment: What was the problem with intersect? Did you `unnest(refs_person)` or were you comparing string to array of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `unnest` the array, best using a `LATERAL` join, before you can `INTERSECT` the results:

```
SELECT rp.rp
   FROM table1
      CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(table1.refs_person) AS rp(rp)
   WHERE id_gps = 'gps_20'
INTERSECT
SELECT id_person
   FROM table2
   WHERE city = 'Paris' AND location = 20;

     rp     
------------
 id_per_234
(1 row)
```